# I can't access mysql on mac os x through terminal

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, glassfish-3

- I have a mac os x.
- I install Netbeans 7.2 with Glassfish
- I install XAMPP

Glassfish is fine, XAMPP has green lights, and netbeans is working.

I want to use MySQL with a Java application that's using Glassfish. I am not having success starting mysql from the terminal. Even after adding XAMPP's mysql to path

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

I still can't get to mysql from terminal. Will someone please help?

Comment: when you say "get to" do you mean start the service? Log in and query some tables? Also, what have you actually tried so far?

Comment: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p should do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$PATH contains directories containing commands, not the executables themselves. It should be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works. Do you how to undo what I did in the OP? (looks like I have to way 6min to accept. Upvote then.)

Comment: Just execute the correct command now. The extra entry in PATH will have no effect. Put the correct command in your `.profile`.